# MongoDB Aggregate Based on Condition on Field with Array of Objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a Collection as Below:-
I would like the query to return the record based on following conditions:

```
usertable is ypcategories
isactive is true
accesstype is webproject
accesstag is localhost4200
```

Appreciate if someone can guide me with the aggregate query.

```
[
        {
            "_id": "637da733d9baa73f1f0b6cab",
            "nid": 1,
            "usertable": "ypcategories",
            "systemtable": "tbl1",
            "access": [
                {
                    "type": "webproject",
                    "tag": "localhost4200"
                }
            ],
            "isactive": true
        },
        {
            "_id": "637da733d9baa73f1f0b6cac",
            "nid": 2,
            "usertable": "ypcategories",
            "systemtable": "tbl2",
            "access": [
                {
                    "type": "webproject",
                    "tag": "localhost4201"
                }
            ],
            "isactive": true
        }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use find as below.

```
db.collection.find({
  "usertable": "ypcategories",
  "isactive": true,
  "access.type": "webproject",
  "access.tag": "localhost4200"
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C8wd40lQ3_G)